# cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: make

I'm trying to use make but I keep getting this error. Tried make clean, updating cpp and some other stuff.

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lhapdf.o -L/home/adrian/Desktop/LHAPDF-6.2.3/src/.libs -lstdc++ -lLHAPDF -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lhapdf.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:485: recipe for target 'all-local' failed
make[2]: * [all-local] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/adrian/Desktop/LHAPDF-6.2.3/wrappers/python'
Makefile:376: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: * [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/adrian/Desktop/LHAPDF-6.2.3/wrappers'
Makefile:509: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: * [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Also, before that I have several:

```
nothing could be done for ''All...''
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to `make` a C++ program using `gcc` - is `g++` installed on your system? Is this your own Makefile, or part of some downloaded software?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What does the command `apt list --installed libstdc++\*` return on your machine? Please [edit] your question to include the output. Also, what project are you trying to build?

Comment: I have the 9.2.0 versions of gcc/g++. The makefile comes from LHAPDF, a program for particle physics. For  ``` apt list --installed libstdc++\* ``` I get: ``` adrian@adrian-VirtualBox:~$ apt list --installed libstdc++\*
Listing... Done
libstdc++-9-dev/bionic,now 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libstdc++6/bionic,now 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed] ```.

Comment: Fixed by removing libstdc and installing again, and aparently this made build-essential to install more things ( i ran it again but i was almost sure i had already done it)

Comment: Great you solved it! Consider [posting an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) or closing your question.

Comment: @Melebius
  libstdc++-9-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,now 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib/focal,now 15:9-2019-q4-0ubuntu1+12build2 all [installed,automatic]
libstdc++6/focal-updates,focal-security,now 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 armhf [installed]